# Form remain the same after submiting using jquery mobile

Tags: forms, caching, jquery-mobile, browser-history

After Im using jquery mobile to submit a form,
but after submition, and going back to form, all fields are not in default value any more. they showing data previously submitted.

(if I press f5, form will reset and works fine for another round only)
Im guessing something remain in browser cache.

Any Idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>       
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
      </head>

<body>
<?php if(!(isset($_GET["submit"]))){ ?>    


    <form action="thisPage.PHP?submit=yes" method="get" >
       <input type="text" value="0" />   
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form>                        


<?php   }else{   ?>
        <a href="thisPage.PHP" > FINISHED</a>
<?php  }  ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the simple and easy answer:
add following line into form tag:

**data-ajax="false"**

so it should be like this:

```
<form action="thisPage.PHP?submit=yes" method="get" data-ajax="false" >
```